# Python decorator shows Assertion error when i used same Decorator for two separate routes in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

When I use Decorator for one route in a flask, I get no error but when I use for two routes it gives me the error

> AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: decorate

Here is the actual code

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
print(__name__)


def make_bold(func):
    def decorate():
        return "<b>" + func() + "</b>"

    return decorate


def make_ittlaic(func):
    def decorate():
        return "<i>" + func() + "</i>"

    return decorate


def make_emphais(func):
    def decorate():
        return "<em>" + func() + "</em>"

    return decorate


def make_underline(func):
    def decorate():
        return "<u>" + func() + "</u>"
    return decorate


@app.route('/')
@make_bold
@make_ittlaic
@make_emphais
@make_underline
def hello_world():
    return 'hello World'

@app.route('/bye')
@make_bold
@make_ittlaic
@make_emphais
@make_underline
def Goodbye():
    return 'Good bye'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions to your problem.

Either rewrite your code as follows, so you split the view function and the data transforming:

```
@make_bold
@make_ittlaic
@make_emphais
@make_underline
def _return_hello_world():
    return 'hello word'

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return _return_hello_world()

@make_bold
@make_ittlaic
@make_emphais
@make_underline
def _return_good_bye():
    return 'Good bye'

@app.route('/bye')
def Goodbye():
    return _return_good_bye()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

or you follow the Flask documentation at https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/viewdecorators/ and use `functools.wrap` to remember the original function name:

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
print(__name__)


def make_bold(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorate():
        return "<b>" + func() + "</b>"

    return decorate


def make_ittlaic(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorate():
        return "<i>" + func() + "</i>"

    return decorate


def make_emphais(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorate():
        return "<em>" + func() + "</em>"

    return decorate


def make_underline(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorate():
        return "<u>" + func() + "</u>"
    return decorate


@app.route('/')
@make_bold
@make_ittlaic
@make_emphais
@make_underline
def hello_world():
    return 'hello World'

@app.route('/bye')
@make_bold
@make_ittlaic
@make_emphais
@make_underline
def Goodbye():
    return 'Good bye'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But why this is happening, So I can avoid these types of errors in the future. I think it is something related to flask

Comment: Have a look at the official Python docs, https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps